# jQuery Prevent submit input to send form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

Got an screen with several forms, one of them has an input (submit).
The JS binding click event for that input is:

```
$('input#next').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   ... some other checks ...
   bSubmit = dateField.val().match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/);
   return bSubmit;
});
```

The issue is that the form is send anyway, which should not happens.

Comment: Try changing to `$("#your_form_id").submit(function(e)` since the user also can submit form with enter.

Comment: Do you mean to do the validation in the submit event for the form, instead in the click event of the submit input, don't you?

Comment: I would do so, yes. Think about it, if the user clicks enter while filling the form, your current code will not prevent the form from sending 'naturally'.

Answer (score 3):

If returned **`bSubmitp` value is other than false**, then the `form` will be submitted.

With a `return true` you are saying that the button must work add is intended... and
-***the submit button is for sending the form-***

If you want to disable at all cost, I suggest a predefined `return false`.

Could be:

- on the [form](/questions/tagged/form) tag in [onsubmit](/questions/tagged/onsubmit) like:

  ```
  <form onsubmit="return false">
  ```
- in your [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) function like you have now but creating a conditional [return](/questions/tagged/return) value, like:

  ```
  <form onsubmit="return yourFunction()">
  ```
- with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) like:

  ```
  $('form').submit(function() {
      // do stuff
      return false;
  });
  ```
- others..

### Edit

Additionally.. you could change the `input type:submit` to just a `button`
Then send the form with `jQuery` (after validation).

*And to prevent form submit when <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed as **@Daniel Lisik** point it out...*
need to acomplish two condition (without javascript)

1. **No** `input type:submit` buttons present in the form
2. **More than one** input field.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, you should put your code into the jQuery `submit` function

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "submit", handler ) in the first variation, and .trigger( "submit" ) in the third.
>
> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit ,
>   , or , or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Example code straight from the jQuery website

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the button type will disable the submit of the input already from start up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input#next').attr("type", "button");

    // own code
    $('input#next').click( function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

And then you can add your own code below.